# Shader Attachment errors. Either invalid Program or shader

Tags: c++, oop, opengl, glsl

I was working on my graphics program. I am trying to abstract features from the Shaders into a class. I tested the regular drawing Code and it works. The shaders run as well but as soon as I start using these OpenGL shader functions it stops working.

```
Shader::Shader(char c)
{
    //program = int(0);
    if (program!=0 || glIsProgram(program))
        glDeleteProgram(program);
    uniforms.clear();

    program = glCreateProgram();
}

void Shader::compileProgram()
{
    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;

    glLinkProgram(program);

    glValidateProgram( program);

    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::string ProgramErrorMessage = std::string();
    ProgramErrorMessage.resize( glm::max(InfoLogLength, int(1)));
    glGetProgramInfoLog(program, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    std::cout << ProgramErrorMessage.c_str() << std::endl;
}

void Shader::addToProgram( std::string File, GLenum type)
{
    std::cout << glGetError() << std::endl;

    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(type);

    std::cout << glewGetErrorString(glGetError()) << std::endl;

    std::string ShaderCode;
    std::ifstream ShaderStream(File, std::ios::in);
    if(ShaderStream.is_open())
    {
        std::string Line = "";
        while(getline(ShaderStream, Line))
            ShaderCode += Line + "\n";
        ShaderStream.close();
    }

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;

    // Compile Vertex Shader
    std::cout << "Compiling shader : " <<  File<< std::endl;
    const char * SourcePointer = ShaderCode.c_str();
    std::cout << SourcePointer << std::endl;
    int length = ShaderCode.size();
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &SourcePointer , &length );

    glCompileShader(shader);

    // Check Vertex Shader
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> ShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    printf("%s\n", &ShaderErrorMessage[0]);

    glAttachShader(program, shader);  //Invalid Operation, eighter Program or shader invalid

    std::cout << glGetError() << std::endl;
```

}

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error? You query whether your shader compiles correctly, but you do not use ''Result'' somewhere.

Comment: The problem is that I don't get any info output. But the Result is 0(GL_FALSE).

I actually solved it the program was for some reason invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Problem was that the Program was invalid.

What I did is this:

```
if(!glIsProgram(program))
    program = glCreateProgram();

glAttachShaders(program, shader);
```

I did the same guard in the constructor. I am still wondering how that happened. I mean I checked the values in Debug and they all seemed valid.